# Loading a user package when connected to the internet is 4x slower as when not

Tags: packages, internet

I have a user-written package (600kB), which I load the standard way:

<<MyPack.m

or

Get["MyPack.m"]

When I am connected to the internet, this takes 18 seconds to load; while when I shut down the internet connection at the computer system level, the same executes in 4.5 seconds.

None of

CurrentValue[\$FrontEndSession, "AllowDownloads"] = False;

CurrentValue[\$FrontEnd, "AllowDownloads"] = False;

\$AllowInternet = False;

change this behavior.

Has anyone a suggestion?

(MacOS 10.15.6, Mathematica 13.2)

Thanks!

UPDATE: Using the suggested print statements, I was able to locate the problem: It is the calls to "Compile" which execute much slower when connected to a network.

Comment: What are you doing inside your package? Is there anything that might try to load data from somewhere, e.g. some Entity queries or similar? Or is there some unavailable network location on your `$Path` that Mathematica tries to search for your package?

Comment: Can Print statements help narrow down which line of code is causing the slowdown?

Comment: Are you using a fresh kernel each time or is it only loading the package without system initialization taken into account?

Comment: Thanks so far! 
- $Path contains only local files
- Print statements are a good idea!
- No, typically I do not actively restart the Kernel when re-loading.